# Security model and existing database

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I have created a database with code first and DbContext.

However this sit separately to the security model database on a new MVC 4 site.

My question is how do i combine my existing database with the security model or should they be kept separate for a valid reason

For example is this the best solution 
http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model

This would recreate the security model and roles when i first ran the application.

Or is there an alternative way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I love the new MVC and Simplemembership Provider for this reason. You can very easily combine your models with the asp.net account models.

When you use the default internet template it creates a context called UsersContext.  To do something simple like add additional fields to a UserProfile object to track in the database you need to do 3 simple things.

1. Add the properties to the model (in the account models if you use the default template)
2. In the register action on the account controller, add the new fields IE:

   ```
   public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           var db = new UsersContext();
           // Attempt to register the user
           try
           {
               WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, Address = model.Address, Company = model.Company, Phone = model.Phone, Country = model.Country, City = model.City, State = model.State, Zip = model.Zip });            
               WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
           }
           catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
           {
               ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
           }
       }

       // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
       return View(model);
   }
   ```

Note the new keyword where I took values from the model passed and just matched them up to the model. (model binding may or may not work here but I haven't tested that yet)

3) Change the register View and model to pass all the info needed

I almost cried when this worked flawlessly the first time with no strange errors.

Good luck